# Formula Mapping in NHibernate to Functions in SQLite or Override Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

i found the following article http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx to help me unit test my NHibernate application.  Most of my tests are working fine but a strange error has been thrown.  From looking at the SQL generated i believe the following fluent mapping is causing the problems:

```
Map(x => x.IsValid).Formula("CASE WHEN dbo.NumPosts(UserID) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END");
```

You'll notice the call to dbo.NumPosts which is a user defined function within my database.  I know there's other ways i could've mapped this property but this is just used as an example.  Basically i need to know how to map this using SQLite.

**Edit:**

After further thoughts would, is it possible to override the mapping for this field in my unit testing project?  Here's my current configuration:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory() {
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
            .AddFromAssembly(typeof(Role).Assembly)
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(c => _configuration = c)
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I don't wish to re-define all the mappings as this would take some time and would become un-maintainable.

I'd appreciate the help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  I was able to say:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "NumPosts", Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class NumPosts : SQLiteFunction {
    public override object Invoke(object[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now all i had to do was add a setting to add the dbo prefix infront of my functions.  This is then set to blank in the test project.

Comment: Where do you detect which nhibernate dialect you are using to handle including 'dbo.' or not?

Comment: I set a property in my global.asax file e.g. "public static string FunctionPrefix = "dbo.";". Then i use that everywhere i say "dbo." in my formulas. Now in your tests you simply have to set it to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the answer in your comment, I was able to get a static bool property to work.

Still I didn't like relying on a global bool variable so I decided to dig further. In NHibernate 3.0 they added events to the Configuration object. In particular I was able to take advantage of the new BeforeBind event on the Configuration object.

I rewrote slightly your CreateSessionFactory() method to show how I did it.

NOTE: In my formula's I always write them as dbo.NumPosts, and the event handler will remove the 'dbo.' if we are running within a SQLite Dialect.

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                           .AddFromAssembly(typeof (Role).Assembly)
                           .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(c =>
                                 {
                                     c.BeforeBindMapping += BeforeBindMappingHandler;
                                     _configuration = c;
                                 })
        .BuildConfiguration()
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static void BeforeBindMappingHandler(object sender, BindMappingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Dialect is SQLiteDialect)) return;

    var properties = e.Mapping.RootClasses
        .SelectMany(r => r.Properties)
        .Where(p => p is HbmProperty)
        .Cast<HbmProperty>()
        .Where(p => p.Formulas.Any());

    foreach (var hbmProperty in properties)
        hbmProperty.formula = hbmProperty.formula.ToLower().Replace("dbo.", "");
}
```