# Fluent Nhibernate In Memory DB testing with SQLite - Syntax Error calling user function in Select statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to get our in memory database using SQLite and Nhibernate 4.0 and Fluent Nhibernate working for integration tests.

One of the entities has this mapping:
`Map(x => x.ShowNameLine2).Formula("FileTaxes.funcMultiplePayersExist(Id, TIN, User_Id)");`

My problem is I'm getting a SQLite syntax error when running the query below (I've stripped out all the non-essential pieces):

```
SELECT 
  batch.Id, 
  FileTaxes.funcMultiplePayersExist(p.Id, p.TIN, p.User_Id) as formula 
FROM "Batch" batch
LEFT OUTER JOIN "BatchPayer" bp ON batch.Id = bp.Batch_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Payer" p ON bp.Payer_id = p.Id
----> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQLite error near "(" : syntax error
```

I've tried defining a custom dialect and registering the function:

```
public class CustomSQLiteDialect : SQLiteDialect
{
    protected override void RegisterColumnTypes()
    {
        base.RegisterColumnTypes();
        ...
    }

    protected override void RegisterFunctions()
    {
        base.RegisterFunctions();
        ...
        RegisterFunction("FileTaxes.funcMultiplePayersExist", new StandardSQLFunction("FileTaxes.funcMultiplePayersExist", NHibernateUtil.Int32));
    }
}
```

We have defined our in memory configuration as below, but I still get the error when running my test using the in memory configuration and in memory session factory:

```
    private static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration _configuration;

    public static FluentConfiguration InMemoryConfiguration()
    {
        if (_inMemoryConfigurationSingleton != null)
            return _inMemoryConfigurationSingleton;

        _inMemoryConfigurationSingleton =
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<FormMap>().Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<Conventions.LengthAttributeConvention>())
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql().Driver<CustomSQLite20Driver>().Dialect<CustomSQLiteDialect>();)
                .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.BeforeBindMapping += BeforeBindMappingHandler;
                    var schemaExport = new SchemaExport(config);
                    _configuration = config;
                    schemaExport.Create(true, true);
                });
        _inMemoryConfigurationSingleton.BuildConfiguration();

        return _inMemoryConfigurationSingleton;
    }

    public static ISessionFactory InMemorySessionFactory()
    {
        return _inMemorySessionFactorySingleton ?? (_inMemorySessionFactorySingleton = InMemoryConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory());
    }
```

Is there something I am missing to get this function to be registered during the in memory configuration setup? Does it have to do with the order the schema export is running?

Comment: Don't know if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389672/formula-mapping-in-nhibernate-to-functions-in-sqlite-or-override-mapping

Comment: I found that post before I asked the question. I still haven't been able to figure it out. When I set a breakpoint in the BeforeBindMapping handler it never gets called. The RegisterFunction method gets called in my customDialect class, but when I inspect the configuration afterwards it shows that no functions are registered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mappings are already built at the time you attach the eventhandler.

I had to build the configuration first and use it as argument to Fluently.Configure to make it work:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.BeforeBindMapping += BeforeBindMappingHandler;
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
   .... 
;
```